# UPDATE multiple row in SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-in

I'm using SQLite and I'm trying to update multiple row using a select statement.

I'm having two tables:

device :

```
ID|Name|param1|param2
----------------------
1 | D1 |  p1  |  p2
2 | D2 |  p1  |  p3
3 | D3 |  p1  |  p4
```

devices_in_groups

```
ID|ID_group|ID_device|
----------------------
1 |    0   |    1    |
2 |    0   |    2    |
3 |    1   |    3    |
```

I would like to update all param1 attribut from all devices in the group 0.

I try something like:

```
UPDATE device SET param1 = p10 
WHERE device.ID = (
SELECT ID_device 
FROM devices_in_groups 
WHERE devices_in_groups.ID_group = 0)
```

It only update the first device (D1) and not the second (D2) unlike there both in the group 0.

How can i do it (in SQLite) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator `IN`:

```
UPDATE device 
SET param1 = 'p10' 
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID_device 
  FROM devices_in_groups 
  WHERE ID_group = 0
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3531b31bb1a3031a9d5d6b15aa84df34).

If your version of SQLite is 3.33.0+ you could also do it with `UPDATE...FROM`:

```
UPDATE device AS d 
SET param1 = 'p10'
FROM devices_in_groups AS g 
WHERE d.ID = g.ID_device AND g.ID_group = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=d49afa76e1da087544d6097ba414e64762328fbd716ca2450586e958298a7464).

Answer (score 1):

Even though your sub query

```
SELECT ID_device 
FROM devices_in_groups 
WHERE devices_in_groups.ID_group = 0
```

returns

```
ID_device
1
2
```

The main query needs to use IN rather than =

= implies you are comparing device.ID value to a query result (rows)

Also p10 needs to be expressed as a string as otherwise you will get an error as there is no column p10.

So changing the query to

```
UPDATE device SET param1 = 'p10' 
WHERE device.ID IN (
SELECT ID_device 
FROM devices_in_groups 
WHERE devices_in_groups.ID_group = 0
)
```

Will work and update all the records in devices table as you expected.